# What is the easiest way to solve this problem , in Cal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The manager of a furniture factory finds that it costs $\$2200$ to manufacture 100 chairs in one day and $\$4800$ to produce 300 chairs in one day.

- Express the cost as a function of the number of chairs produced, assuming that it is linear. Then sketch the graph.
- What is the slope of the graph and

Comment: Don't use the title to give a complete problem statement.  Edit the body of your Question to give a complete problem statement and *context* of a kind that reflects the research or other effort you put into solving the problem before posting.  For example, where did you find the problem?  What makes it important or challenging?  Do you know definitions for the terms in the problem or is that threshold issue what is holding you back?

Comment: If you haven't worked on your subject, you cannot expect an answer from us.

Comment: i have tried my best to slove this issue i'm not so good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the number of chairs produced to be $x$ and the cost to production of those chairs be denoted as $y$.

Since the relation between cost and the number of chairs produced is linear, we need to find the equation of the line that passes through $(100, 2200)$ and $(300, 4800)$.

The slope of a line passing through two points is given by $m = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. Therefore we have $m = \frac{4800-2200}{300-100} = 13$.

Hence the equation of the line passing through $(100,2200)$ with a slope of $13$ is $y-2200 = 13(x-100)$. Solve for $y$ and you should get $y = 13x+900$.